# Symfony2 - Call static property from service

Tags: web-services, symfony, service, controller, symfony-2.4

I am calling a service within my Simfony2's controller's method.

No problem at all, it works fine.

```
function getFilterListBrandAction($brand_id = 0, $url_params = array()){
 $b = $this->get('brand.service');
 return $this->render('BundleMybundle:Page:page.html.twig', array(
            'param1' => $b->getParam(),
            'do_not_change' => $b::$filter_accepted['brand']
        ));     
    }
```

Troubles arrive when i try to call the static property `$b::$filter_accepted['brand']` from the service previously instantiated. On the contrary, i have no problem for the other method `$b->getParam()`.

There's a way to call a static property / method from a service?

Comment: Do you see any error message?

Comment: And show result of `var_dump($filter_accepted['brand'])` of this array, please

Comment: I think that It's a generally bad idea. What if `$filter_accepted['brand']` returns some unexpected value? Sory, but I'dont remember if I saw construction like that in documentation. Maybe your goal is possible to achieve other way? Like via add `checkChangeStatus($brand)` method to your `brand.service`. You could do some logic in this method and return value.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's possible to access public properties from a service.

This works for me:

**Your service:**

```
/**
 * Your Service
 */
class YourService
{
    public static $filter_accepted = array('brand' => 'my brand');
}
```

**Controller**

```
class YourController extends ContainerAware
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $service = $this->container->get('acme.my_service');

        var_dump($service::$filter_accepted);
        // Returns: array(1) { ["brand"]=> string(8) "my brand" }

        var_dump($service::$filter_accepted['brand']);
        // Returns: string(8) "my brand"
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you don't have the correct service. Post the code of your service and the config.yml file where your declare it. Again, this should work as I tried it myself. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was very foolish. I was searching in the wrong service! Thank you again! :)